# What would be a minimal example of a Django site that create and deliver a file?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I wrote my first script a few weeks ago after learning Python. Now I have to make it available on a webserver. For that I plan to use Django. I could use Flask for something this small but I have to learn Django anyway.

The script currently runs on Google Colab's Jupyter and generate an Excel file with data extracted from an API. It ends by:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(my_file)
...
workbook.close()
files.downlad(my_file)
```

I have to make a Django app that display :

- a button to generate and download the file
- a list of recently generated files with a download link

I don't find the documentation to be so clear. It is focused on uploading files with forms.

I get that I have to create a file object in model.py and to list existing objects in the template with a for loop. What is less clear is how to save the generated output in a file object.

Comment: Do you need to save the file in a database or a storage service such as s3 buckets? Or you just need to save the file into a directory?

Comment: Just in a directory of the server.